# How to save locally saved xml file into .plist file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, plist

I need to write and update XML file based on nodes.

For that I found that I need to convert local XML file into plist file.

Then I can able to update, read and write into plist file as we need.

But I didn't found any sample code regarding this.

Can anyone please post some code regarding **how can I save local xml file into plist file**?

**How can I read, write and update that locally saved plist file**?

Comment: `[[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myXMLFileURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]] writeToURL:myPlistURL atomically:YES];` :)

Comment: @WTP Y dont you answer it instead of commenting???

Comment: @WTP i need to convert locally saved xml file,not from url

Comment: @MaheshBabu a URL can be local (`+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`), it's even recommended by Apple over a path. @Kingofbliss if you read it you can see it's kind of a joke.

Comment: people who down vote please add comment.i don't think why u people down vote

Comment: @WTP i got it..:) @Mahesh waitng for an answer for you question. +1 for ur comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to parse the XML file into `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` and `NSString` objects and then you can save it with `-[NSDictionary/NSArray writeToURL:atomically:]`.

There are various tutorials available on how to parse XML. I recommend [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) as it's extremely fast.

You would parse the XML file and put the data into an `NSDictionary` with keys like this:

- Name: `NSString` with the name of the element
- Attributes: `NSDictionary` of attributes
- Text: `NSString` containing the text in the element
- Sub-elements: `NSArray` of sub-elements (array of dictionaries like this one)